How can I deduce a capacitance of a capacitor without existing formulaes?
Understanding Charge Accumulation in Capacitors Connected in Series
I've been exploring the behavior of capacitors connected in series and developing a conceptual model to understand how charge accumulates without relying on standard formulas. Here's my current approach:

Voltage Drops and Charge Accumulation:

I've conceptualized the voltage drop $V_{dc1}$ across the first capacitor $C1$ as $V_{dc1} = \int_0^t kr \space dt$, where $k$ is a proportionality constant. This integral represents the accumulation of charge $Q$ over time due to the rate $r$ of electron flow.


Total Voltage and Charge Distribution:

In series configuration, the total voltage $V_{in}$ is distributed across the capacitors, affecting the voltage drops $V_{dc1}$ and $V_{dc2}$ across each capacitor.


Determining the Proportionality Constant $k$:



My model depends on $k$, which represents the relationship governing the charge accumulation for a coulomb of charge moving through the external circuit with a given potential $E$. I aim to determine $k$ through experimental data or by leveraging known capacitor characteristics. This constant is essential for accurately predicting charge accumulation and voltage drops within my conceptual framework.

Question:

How can I experimentally or theoretically determine the value of $k$ in my model? Given that $k$ depends on specific capacitor properties, what experiments or methods can I employ to establish this constant? Additionally, how can I use my conceptual model to deduce the total charge accumulation in capacitors connected in series?

Your insights and suggestions would greatly help refine my understanding and application of this conceptual approach.
Update
To conclude, I was trying to understand the behavior of capacitors in series:
$V_{\text{in}} = V_{d1} + V_{d2}$
The voltage drops across the electric components explain the input voltage $(V_{\text{in}})$. At steady state, the capacitance values explain the respective voltage drops:
$k_1 Q + k_2 Q = (k_1 + k_2) Q = k_{total} \cdot Q$
Here, $( Q $) represents the charge, analogous to current.
$(k_{text{total}} = k_1 + k_2)$.
Using the formula:
$\frac{1}{C_{total}} = \frac{1}{C_1} + \frac{1}{C_2}$
where $( C_{\text{total}} $) is the total capacitance of the capacitors in series, $( C_1 $) and $( C_2 )$ are the capacitances of the individual capacitors.

Updated the question with explanation to calculate total capacitance when capacitors are in series.

Since you are assuming $k$ is a constant, you can take it outside of your integral formula to give
$V(t) = k \int_0^t r \space dt$
But $\int_0^t r \space dt$ is the charge $Q(t)$ that has accumulated on the capacitor at time $t$. So we can rewrite this as
$V(t) = kQ(t)$
So your constant $k = \frac {V(t)}{Q(t)}$ is the reciprocal of the capacitance of the capacitor. This is sometimes called the elastance of the capacitor.
The capacitance (or, equivalently, the elastance) of a capacitor can be experimentally determined by placing it in a circuit with a capacitor with known capacitance, or by measuring its rate of discharge over time when placed in a circuit with a known resistor.

Thank you @gandalf61 for the rewrite.
